# Ver cambios realizados en CSS de PHP con WampServer

Tags: php

Estoy creando una sección con php y estoy haciendo unos cambios en el css. El problema es que al refrescar, normalmente se muestran los cambios que he realizado, pero no me cargan y no puedo visualizar los cambios que he hecho. Por si acaso uso wampserver.

Comment: Borra la caché al refrescar, o por defecto tu navegador cargará el archivo css que tiene en ella.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que sea el caché, presiona *CTRL + F5* para borrarlo.

Comment: Ya dijeron lo del caché en los comentarios, creo que sería mejor esperar a que se aclare mejor la situación.